Interpretation of power in WPT systems - given a requirement of power, find an adequate value for the inductance
I need to design the coils for a WPT system. I was given something like a note where the topology was drawn, and then with all the maths and reasoning the main formulas for the power of the circuit. In order to ask the question I need to explain that briefly. This is the circuit:

Here, V1 is the source on primary side, and V2 is the load―is the input for a diode rectifier which goes to a battery charger, still don't understand why was modeled with a dissipating power source but left that aside for now.
So, assume that the capacitors will synthonize the RLC circuits for resonance. Then, write Kirchoff laws:
$$V_1 = I_1 R_1 - j \omega M I_2$$
$$V_2 = -I_2 R_2 + j \omega M I_1$$
Now, solve the system of equations for \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$. Knowing that \$V_2\$ is the input of a rectifier, then \$V_2\$ and \$I_2\$ will have the same phase. Hence, \$V_2\$ is 90° degrees ahead with respect to \$V_1\$. Therefore:
$$I_1 =  \frac{-j V_2}{\omega M} \frac{\left(1 + \frac{V_1}{V_2} \frac{R_2}{\omega M}\right) }{1 + \frac{R_1 R_2}{(\omega M)^2}}$$
$$I_2 =  \frac{j V_1}{\omega M} \frac{\left(1 - \frac{V_1}{V_2} \frac{R_1}{\omega M}\right) }{1 + \frac{R_1 R_2}{(\omega M)^2}}$$
Finally, to get the input and output power, just do:
$$P_i = V_1 I_1 = \frac{V_1 V_2}{\omega M} \frac{\left(1 + \frac{V_1}{V_2} \frac{R_2}{\omega M}\right) }{1 + \frac{R_1 R_2}{(\omega M)^2}} \approx \frac{V_1 V_2}{\omega M}$$
$$P_o = V_2 I_2 = \frac{V_1 V_2}{\omega M} \frac{\left(1 - \frac{V_2}{V_1} \frac{R_1}{\omega M}\right) }{1 + \frac{R_1 R_2}{(\omega M)^2}} \approx \frac{V_1 V_2}{\omega M}$$
Where the last approximations assume that the resistances \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ can be neglected.
Now the question. I understand all the math involved but I can't understand the interpretation of the result. In other words, how can I determine the proper value of mutual inductance I need? I thought it should be high, because that would increase merit factor. But if you make inductance of the coils too high, then \$M\$ will be high, then, since \$\omega M\$ is on the denominator, the power I will transmit... decreases??? Should I make my coils small in order to lower \$M\$ and to increase power?? How can I predict if my coil will be able to give the required power? Does inductance plays a key role in power transfer? If so, how? Does it depends on another thing?
EDIT
Just after I posted, I discovered something, maybe it helps, maybe it  brings more confusion. Before the approximations were made, just set \$M := 0\$, then it follows that \$P_i = V_1^2 / R_1\$, \$P_o = V_2^2 / R_2\$. This is the dissipated power on a resonant uncoupled RLC circuit. Now I wonder if actually the power formulas refer to the power that is lost on each side, instead of the power that is transferred to the next side.
Just in case, if you want further context, I asked to a professor about the minimum value of inductance I should aim in order to satisfy the power requirements and he gave me the note I posted and said ‘read this, from this you will get the answer you're looking for’. But I don't see where is the relationship! That bring me to this site.
